# Handling simple GET request using Spring MVC gives 404

Tags: java, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

**What is needed:**

There is simple web application running on Tomcat at address `http://localhost:8080/`.
Handler for following URL should be added:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/request/report/custom_report?from=2013-10-12&to=2014-10-12&download=true
```

which will simply write to the `HttpServletResponse` some data i.e. **no views are involved**.

**What was done:**

1. As per [official Spring MVC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) following mapping of `DispatcherServlet` was added to `web.xml`

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/request/*</url-pattern>
       <!-- PLEASE NOTE that mapping to /* is not an option -->
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
2. Now, because latest `spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE` is used I would like to add above mentioned handler with the minimum `XML or Java` configuration possible, so I create controller class:

   ```
   package org.yura.servlet.spring;

   @Controller
   public class SpringRequestController {

       @RequestMapping(value = "/report/custom_report",
                       method = GET,
                       produces = "application/pdf")
       public void getCustomReport(
                   @RequestParam("from") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") final Date from,
                   @RequestParam("to") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") final Date to,
                   @RequestParam("download") final boolean download,
                   final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

       takeParamsAndWriteReportAsPdfToServletResponse(from, to, download, response.getOutputStream());
   }
   ```
3. Then, in order for this `Controller` to be "picked up" by Spring I put `springDispatcher-servlet.xml` right next to `web.xml` in `WEB-INF` folder with following configuration (please advise if it can be simplified even more):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

       <context:component-scan base-package="org.yura.servlet.spring" />

   </beans>
   ```

**The Problem**

With this configuration, after starting Tomcat and navigating to above mentioned URL I get **Error 404**.

**Question 1**: Please advise what is wrong with handler URLs - should I specify them as relative or what? (because as per logs, DispatcherServlet is created normally)

**Question 2**: Is it possible to move configuration from `springDispatcher-servlet.xml` to my `Controller` class in order not to scatter request-handling logic across multiple files.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: turn your logging for `org.springframework.web.*` to debug, should help diagnose problem.

Comment: Judging by the URL you are hitting, it looks like you are deploying to an application server, like Tomcat or the like.  If that is the case, then I would expect to see the deployment context in the URL after the hostname/port (ie. as the first part of the URI part).  This would usually be the WAR name, unless you override it via the web.xml. For instance, if my WAR was called `MyApp.war` my URL would be `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/request/report/custom_report` blah blah blah. I believe that is your missing piece.

Comment: Your are using `produces="application/pdf"`. Are you sure that the client can accept that response?

Comment: @CodeChimp yes, I'm using Tomcat and deploying to `webapps/ROOT` folder, so webapp can be accessed right at `http://localhost:8080/` and I would like to add handler for URL `http://localhost:8080/request2/report/custom_report` blah blah blah :)

Comment: @geoand yes, I'm sure that client can accept that response - in fact I've implemented handler for such URL using plain Servlets and it works - handles such requests as expected and downloads PDF. Now, when I re-implemented handler for mentioned URL using mentioned approach - I'm receiving error 404, which means that handler for this GET request is missing, so `Content-Type` is not the problem.

Comment: @Taylor thanks - that's a good point, will add logs to this post right after I turn logging on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't enabled your MVC stack. Add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

to your `springDispatcher-servlet.xml` (along with the appropriate namespaces).

The configuration in `springDispatcher-servlet.xml` is not simply request handling configuration. It can contain any bean declaration. If anything, you can move it to a Java configuration, but it should not be part of your `@Controller` source code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice! Somewhy I thought that `mvc:annotation-driven` is enabled in `Spring MVC 4` by default... Will try now and report back

Comment: You are right - adding `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to `springDispatcher-servlet.xml` did the job! Thanks a lot for your help!